# Splitting string into 2 dimensional table in Lua

Tags: string, split, lua, lua-patterns

Let's say I have this string:

```
map_data = "     *-*  ;    /|x|\ ;   *-*-*-*;  /|x|x|x|;-*-*-*-*-*;  \|x|x|x|;   *-*-*-*;    \|x|/ ;     *-*  ;"
```

I would like to split the string into an ordered table at the semicolons. Once I have done that I would like to take each element of the table and split each character into an ordered table (nested within the first table). The idea is to create a 2 dimensional table for an ascii map.

I have tried this (but it's not working and I also suspect there is an easier way):

```
map_data = "     *-*  ;    /|x|\ ;   *-*-*-*;  /|x|x|x|;-*-*-*-*-*;  \|x|x|x|;   *-*-*-*;    \|x|/ ;     *-*  ;"

map = {}

p = 1
pp = 1
for i in string.gmatch(map_data, "(.*);") do
    map[p] = {}
    for ii in string.gmatch(i, ".") do
        map[p][pp] = ii
        pp = pp + 1
    end
    p = p + 1
end
```

Comment: Don't modify the original code like that, it makes the current answer invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been years since I've touched Lua but assuming you fix the escape character issue can't you then just do something along the lines of...

```
map = {{}} -- map initially contains one empty line 
for i = 1, #map_data do
    local c = map_data:sub(i,i)
    if c == ';' then
        map[#map+1] = {} -- add another line to the end of map
    else
        map[#map][ #map[#map] + 1] = c -- add c to last line in map
    end
end
```

Comment: One more quick question though. Let's say I wanted to store the characters in the table like: map[y][x].value instead of directly into map[y][x]. How would I need to change the code to not get a nil value error?

Answer (score 3):

To start with, the string `map_data` is invalid, because `\` needs to be escaped. Or you could use the long string syntax `[[ ... ]]`:

```
map_data = [[     *-*  ;    /|x|\ ;   *-*-*-*;  /|x|x|x|;-*-*-*-*-*;  \|x|x|x|;   *-*-*-*;    \|x|/ ;     *-*  ;]]
```

The problem of the pattern `(.*);` is, the modifier `*` is greedy. Instead, use `-` modifier which is lazy:

```
for i in string.gmatch(map_data, "(.-);") do
```

Comment: So I made the changes and for some reason it's only capturing the first line: "     *-*  ". Is there something else I've done wrong?

Comment: @EliBell - `pp = 1` should be moved inside outer loop.